# Python Fabric inserting a variable to the run command

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to add a variable from my config file `config.PATH` to this Fabric run command:

```
run('cd $(config.PATH); mkdir releases; mkdir shared; mkdir packages;', fail='ignore')
```

But I get the error:

**typeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fail'**

How can I achieve that I'm trying to do? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that `run` doesn't accept an argument named `fail`, and indeed, if you look at the [fabric docs for the `run()` function](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run), you will find no mention of such parameter.

This has nothing to do with trying to inject a variable in your command.

If your purpose is to ignore errors, you should use either `warn_only` or `quiet`. From the documentation:

> To ignore non-zero return codes, specify `warn_only=True`. To both
>   ignore non-zero return codes and force a command to run silently,
>   specify `quiet=True`.

As for the injection of the config variable, I do not believe it will work. In general, you can use python's regular string formatting facilities, but for your use case you're best to use fabric's [`cd` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd):

```
with cd(config.PATH):
    run('YOUR COMMAND HERE')
```

This will change the remote working directory for the duration of the command (or commands) in the block.

Comment: You are right thanks. will the config.PATH variable actually work tho?

Comment: Thank you, you have been a huge help  :)